# Greedy Heuristic for an Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I've read through several books/papers on optimization, where in particular I came across the term $\textit{Greedy Heuristic}$ in a few of the books/papers on discrete optimization. How does one derive such a heuristic for an optimization problem, and how do we use the heuristic to solve the problem?

I've only managed to find one such example which came in the form of a question from a book (without answers provided sadly). The problem is stated as follows:

$\textbf{Q:}$ Consider the following private-hire contract optimization problem:

The company created a forecast for a period of six months, for the required number of cars needed per month - $\textbf{Jan}$: 40, $\textbf{Feb}$: 25, $\textbf{Mar}$: 36, $\textbf{Apr}$: 37, $\textbf{May}$: 30, $\textbf{Jun}$: 35.

Also, the cars were rented on contracts with fixed prices as follows - 3-month contracts at 8000 per car, 4-month contracts at 9000 per car, and 5-month contracts at 10000 per car.

Furthermore, 6 cars are avaiable for use from the previous period, and their contract expires by the end of Feburary. The manager of the company needs to know how many contracts of each type are needed at the start of each month in order to satisfy the forecasted number of cars for the next six-month period.

$\textbf{Objective:}$ To minimize cost, and to have no cars on contract at the end of June.

$\textbf{Query:}$ As stated in the first few lines of my post, how can I derive such a heuristic for the above problem as an example, and how can one use it to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you need an exact solution?

Comment: No I do not. I just want to gain an understanding on such an application through the methods/ motivation(s) from the heuristic's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heuristics (as opposed to metaheuristics) are often (usually?) created based on some intuition into good solutions or some specific aspect of the problem structure. The term "greedy heuristic" actually refers to a class of heuristics, which in general terms go along the following lines: make the first decision based on getting the best "bang for the buck"; recalculate where you are at (needs, capacities, etc.); make the next decision to get best "bang for the buck"; repeat.

So a greedy heuristic for your problem might look like the following. Use as many five month contracts as it takes to cover January demand (after netting out left over contracts). Figure the revised net demand for February and cover that with five month contracts. Repeat for March, only now using four month contracts. In April, add as many three month contracts as it takes to cover the rest of the period.

A fancier heuristic might start with that and look for places where a cheaper contract could be switched for a more expensive one (do it if the solution remains feasible, don't do it if it leaves uncovered demand).

Comment: For the 'fancier heuristic' do you mean looking for the cheapest contract instead rather than a more expensive one, as the objective is to minimize the costs incurred by the private hire company? Do correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: Also, just to clarify - for February, with regards to the 5-month contracts, do we take into account the updated number of cars needed in February for the contracts, or do we select say - 37 (demand in April) so that the demands for the remaining periods are satisfied in "one-shot", in February? Again, do correct me if this is a misconception about the greedy heuristic. Thanks!

Comment: First point: Yes, I meant replace a more expensive contract with a less expensive one that would still get the job done.

Comment: Second point: That's up to you. There's no single definition for "greedy heuristic". My inclination would be something like this. Buy 34 five month contracts in January, which gets you through January and February. Add two four month contracts in March, and one three month contract in April. You need 33 cars in June; whether to buy three or five month contracts depends on how you want to prepare for the next planning cycle.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and detailed explanation! This clears up my doubts quite a bit! :)